# Prove that if $p, p+2$ and $p+4$ are primes, then $p=3$

Tags: proof-verification

Since $p+2$ and $p + 4$ are prime, $3$ doesn't divide either of them. But then $3 \mid p+3$, which implies $3 \mid p$. Since $p$ is prime, then $p = 3$.

Is it this simple?

Comment: Your solution is correct. I would only add that $p+2$ and $p+4$ are primes which are bigger than $3$ (it is obvious but still should be written), this is why $3$ doesn't divide them.

Comment: If I was teaching an undergraduate introduction to proofs, I would ask for some justification of the "But then" assertion. As written, it sort of sounds like you're saying that if $3$ doesn't divide two numbers, then it does divide their average....

Comment: @BarryCipra I thought it was obvious that I was using that $3$ divides any three consecutive numbers, but I see how that is a valid concern. Thanks.

Comment: When first learning to write proofs, it helps to be super explcit, even if it makes your proofs tedious and verbose. (If the grader doesn't like it, that's their tough luck.) As you get more experienced, you get a feel for which details are crucial and which ones can be skipped over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$3$ has to divide exactly one of $p, p+2, p+4$ (from simple congruency conditions). Since these are assumed to be primes, this implies $3$ IS one of $p, p+2, p+4$. Checking the $3$ conditions, this leads to $p=3$.

Comment: Thanks. I'm accepting your answer and upvoting you too since you're a new contributor.

Comment: That's great. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $ $ They're $\,\equiv p,\, p\!+\!1,\, p\!+\!2\pmod 3\,$ so one is divisible by $3$

Comment: Isn't that sort of exactly what I wrote?

Comment: @Matheus The hinted ideas is to use that a sequence of $n$ consecutive integers contains a multiple of $n$ or, equivalently, forms a complete set sof residues (remainders). It's not clear if that's what you are using.

Comment: I see now. Thanks!